# Get current GPS position in iOS UITest

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

Is it possible to get the current GPS position of the phone/simulator in a UITest test-case?

One possible workaround would be to run a test app in the background and communicate with that app in the test-case but I want to avoid that if possible.

Comment: You should probably simulate the device location so that you have a known location for your testing

Comment: @Paulw11 We already do this using a GPX file, but I want to know the exact location at a given moment.

Comment: Import CoreLocation into your XCUI tests, setup a CLLocationManger and start tracking location there?

Comment: @alexkent Doesn’t work sadly. In my testing it never showed the permissions prompt.

Comment: No I guess not, XCUI test target doesn't show UI… Maybe you could hack around it making a helper app with the same bundle Id as the XCUI test target. Helper app just requests Location permission; you launch it once, accept the permission, then run the real app tests again? No idea if this would work :D

Answer (score 3):

#### TL;DR:

Example project: https://github.com/JakubMazur/SO52339694

---

The principle of testing is that you control environment, so for testing you should be using one of predefined location or put one of your's location into `.gpx` file:

example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gpx version="1.1">
<wpt lat="50.12108905423" lon="39.9260224404235">
</wpt>
</gpx>
```

If you said like in comment a location in a given moment inside UITesting, that's not gonna be possible in real time, but you can combine couple of things to get location from time couple of seconds/minutes back.

Here what I would do:

1. There is a tool called [corelocationcli](https://github.com/fulldecent/corelocationcli) available through homebrew. If you install it this will give you current coordinates.
2. Then I will create file linked in my xcode project in tests let's call it `genarated.gpx` and filled it with any data on this point.
3. Then I will wrote a script like this:

code

```
#!/bin/bash

latitude="$(CoreLocationCLI -format \"%latitude\")"
longitude="$(CoreLocationCLI -format \"%longitude\")"

echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>
<gpx version=\"1.1\">
<wpt lat=${longitude} lon=${latitude}>
</wpt>
</gpx>" > generated.gpx
```

4. And apply this as a build phase:

[image]

That way getting location get a couple of seconds before starting an UITests, but if you can live with this couple of seconds delay this solution should work for you.

Example project [you can find on github](https://github.com/JakubMazur/SO52339694)

Comment: This would be an option. I my case it’s important to get the location as accurate as possible. Thats why I would like to get the location in the UITest similar to LocationControler in the normal app. If that’s not possible (or no other answers) I‘ll accept this workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have control over the app code, and not just the test cases code :

- Implement location tracking in the app itself
- Expose the current /
  last known location with timestamp via the tracking class' public
  (static?) method
- Access it in your test case addition to the functionality being tested

This makes your test cases less robust but should get you the desired behavior

Comment: Oh sorry i forgot to mention that. I don’t have access the apps code.